# Type mismatch error 13 while comparing strings vba

Tags: vba, excel, boolean, type-mismatch

Is there something wrong with this syntax?

```
If xlwsIAR.Cells(x, 5).Text <> "FTD-OPEN" Or "FTD-CLOSE" Then
  ''action
  ''action
  ''action
End if
```

because I am trying to check a cell if it has the specific criteria.

Comment: The second part of your comparison  ("FTD-OPEN" Or "FTD-CLOSE") will return TRUE which the IFstatement then compares to a string value. OR is a logical comparison operator and not a way of defining alternative comparisons in an inequality. You need to include the complete inequality twice (on either side of the OR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB/VBA is specific in the conditions of a comparison. While it is possible to compare to an array of constants, your syntax is probably better built brick-by-brick.

```
If UCase(xlwsIAR.Cells(x, 5).Text) <> "FTD-OPEN" And UCase(xlwsIAR.Cells(x, 5).Text) <> "FTD-CLOSE" Then
```

I threw in a couple of [UCase functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264252.aspx) since your string constants were upper case and VBA string comparisons are by default case sensitive.

Comment: BTW, your data would have to have a very specific circumstance where you needed to compare to the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) and not the [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or [Range.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx). Either of the latter is more efficient for a string retrieval; .Value2 is the better of the two.

Comment: I would suggest to improve this answer and stick to DRY principle and assign `UCase(xlwsIAR.Cells(x, 5).Text)` to a variable and than use the variable in the `if` statement. Never compose the programs by brute copy and paste :) Then this piece will be not only more efficient and maintainable but also more readable, given you make up a good name for the variable. :)

Comment: A logical expression of the form `x <> y Or x <> z` (where `y<>z` is `True`) will (unless I am really confused) always return `True` because, if `x<>y` is `False` (i.e. `x=y`) then `x<>z` must be `True` and vice-versa.

Comment: So I suspect the statement should be `UCase(xlwsIAR.Cells(x, 5).Text) <> "FTD-OPEN" And UCase(xlwsIAR.Cells(x, 5).Text) <> "FTD-CLOSE"`.

Comment: Good catch on the logic slip. I will adjust above.

Comment: thanks, you are right. mechanically, this condition is too vague.

I used like/not like and wildcard which worked... ty anyway